# Jquery Hover Title, fold out div

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of articles with titles and excerpts, I want to have the excerpt fold out when hovering the title. here is my code:

```
<div class="search-post" id="post-290">

    <div class="posty-content">
    <h2 class="title trigger"><a href="http://qa.cidev.info/case-study/future-shop-case-study/" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Future Shop Case Study">Future Shop Case Study</a></h2>

    <div class="entry boxed">
        <p>Overview Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis nascetur ridiculus mus lorem ipsum. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis nascetur ridiculus mus lorem ipsum. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Cras&#8230;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="float-divider"></div>
</div>

<div class="search-post" id="post-288">

    <div class="posty-content">
    <h2 class="title trigger"><a href="http://qa.cidev.info/case-study/tiger-direct-case-study/" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Tiger Direct Case Study">Tiger Direct Case Study</a></h2>

    <div class="entry boxed">
        <p>Overview Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis nascetur ridiculus mus lorem ipsum. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis nascetur ridiculus mus lorem ipsum. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Cras&#8230;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="float-divider"></div>
</div>

<div class="search-post" id="post-286">

    <div class="posty-content">
    <h2 class="title trigger"><a href="http://qa.cidev.info/case-study/kfc-case-study/" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to KFC Case Study">KFC Case Study</a></h2>

    <div class="entry boxed">
        <p>Overview Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis nascetur ridiculus mus lorem ipsum. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis nascetur ridiculus mus lorem ipsum. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Cras&#8230;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="float-divider"></div>
</div>
```

and my current jquery

```
$('.trigger').hover(function() {
   $('.boxed').show("slow");
});
```

The problem is when I hover over a trigger, all boxed items are showing, I just want the current post content box to open, any ideas??

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
$('.trigger').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.boxed').show("slow");
});
```

It will only show the `.boxed` elements inside the parent of the clicked `.trigger` element.

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to mention, how do i make it toggle

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
$('.trigger').hover(function() {
   $(this).siblings('.boxed').show("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are referencing a class for your `show` method.  You should be referencing an ID instead, or at least you need to uniquely identify which div should pop out.

please try replacing your jQuery code with this, it should work:

```
$('.trigger').hover(function() {
   $(this).parent().find('.boxed').show("slow");
});
```

in order to hide the popup after you stop hovering, use this code:

```
$('.trigger').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.boxed').show("slow");
},function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.boxed').hide("slow");
});
```